# How can I test basic auth in my rspec controller examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, basic-authentication

I have some rails controllers that use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` -- how can I set the user/pass in my rspec examples?

I'm surprised to not have been able to find this elsewhere on the web, so maybe I'm using the wrong terms? -- I found some very old things, or what seems to me like very complicated things. Seems like at this point rspec would either have direct support for this, or a tidy idiomatic solution.

Comment: Did you see this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013770/solved-rspec-rails-3-1-integration-test-how-to-send-post-request-headers-for

Comment: thanks! that led me to figure out a simpler way...

Answer (score 6):

this works. thanks to @zetetic pointing me in the right direction

```
before do
  @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
end
```

Comment: Using string interpolation:
`@request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = "Basic #{Base64::encode64('username:password')}"`